# Ternary always returning true condition? But should not be

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hello I am troubleshooting code,

I'm new to javascript and have no idea why the below ternary is always returning the true condition. I do not want to add one month if I have a null or empty string. I want to simply make the variable a false boolean.

But I always get today's date + a month.

Am I missing something here?

```js
(Foo.Bar.limp?.bizkit?.rollin !== null && !Foo.Bar.limp?.bizkit?.rollin !=="" ? moment(Foo.Bar.limp?.bizkit?.rollin).add(1, "months").toISOString() : false)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, you're missing the validation of undefined. Right now you're using strict equal instead of just equal, you can try:

Option 1

```js
Boolean(Foo.Bar.limp?.bizkit?.rollin) ? moment(Foo.Bar.limp?.bizkit?.rollin).add(1, "months").toISOString() : false)
```

In, this way you will accept anything which is not empty, null, undefined
P.S. you can use: `!!value` instead of `Boolea(value)` (because in JS we have the falsy value concept

Option 2:

```js
(Foo.Bar.limp?.bizkit?.rollin != null && !Foo.Bar.limp?.bizkit?.rollin != '' ? moment(Foo.Bar.limp?.bizkit?.rollin).add(1, "months").toISOString() : false)
```

It's what you have with more flexibility, one more time based on falsy values.

Comment: Thank you @joseglego I really appreciate your snippet. You solved my problem!